# Numba much slower than plain python, from Pandas documentation

Tags: python, pandas, jit, numba, numexpr

I am aiming to replicate the results from the enhancing performing guide of the pandas documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html

The numba implementation of the example should be really fast, even faster than the Cython implementation. I succesfully implemented the Cython code, but although Numba should be really easy to implement (just adding a decorator right?) it is super slow, even slower than the plain python implementation. Does anyone have any idea how so?

Results:

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import numba

import cpythonfunctions



def f(x):
    return x * (x - 1)


def integrate_f(a, b, N):
    s = 0
    dx = (b - a) / N
    for i in range(N):
        s += f(a + i * dx)
    return s * dx

@numba.jit
def f_plain_numba(x):
    return x * (x - 1)


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def integrate_f_numba(a, b, N):
    s = 0
    dx = (b - a) / N
    for i in range(N):
        s += f_plain_numba(a + i * dx)
    return s * dx


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def apply_integrate_f_numba(col_a, col_b, col_N):
    n = len(col_N)
    result = np.empty(n, dtype="float64")
    assert len(col_a) == len(col_b) == n
    for i in range(n):
        result[i] = integrate_f_numba(col_a[i], col_b[i], col_N[i])
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "a": np.random.randn(1000),
            "b": np.random.randn(1000),
            "N": np.random.randint(100, 1000, (1000)),
            "x": "x",
        }
    )


    start = time.perf_counter()
    df.apply(lambda x: integrate_f(x["a"], x["b"], x["N"]), axis=1)
    print('pure python takes {}'.format(time.perf_counter() - start))

    '''
    CYTHON
    '''
    # cythonize the functions (plain python functions to C)
    start = time.perf_counter()
    df.apply(lambda x: cpythonfunctions.integrate_f_plain(x["a"], x["b"], x["N"]), axis=1)
    print('cython takes {}'.format(time.perf_counter() - start))

    # create cdef and cpdef (typed fucntions, with int, double etc..)
    start = time.perf_counter()
    df.apply(lambda x: cpythonfunctions.integrate_f_typed(x["a"], x["b"], x["N"]), axis=1)
    print('cython typed takes {}'.format(time.perf_counter() - start))

    # In above function, most time was spend calling series.__getitem__ and series.__get_value
    # ---> This stems from the apply apart. Cythonize this!
    start = time.perf_counter()
    cpythonfunctions.apply_integrate_f(df["a"].to_numpy(), df["b"].to_numpy(), df["N"].to_numpy())
    print('cython integrated takes {}'.format(time.perf_counter() - start))


    # Remove memory checks
    start = time.perf_counter()
    cpythonfunctions.apply_integrate_f_wrap(df["a"].to_numpy(), df["b"].to_numpy(), df["N"].to_numpy())
    print('cython integrated takes {}'.format(time.perf_counter() - start))

    '''
    including JIT
    '''

    start = time.perf_counter()
    apply_integrate_f_numba(df["a"].to_numpy(), df["b"].to_numpy(), df["N"].to_numpy())
    print('numba.jit apply integrate takes {}'.format(time.perf_counter() - start))
```

Dependencies:

[image]

Comment: Does this include compilation time? Use `cache=True` to persist the compiled function, and then rerun your test. See here for more details: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#cache

Comment: Your input also seems a bit small for this type of test. I'd suggest increasing the size of the DataFrame by 1 or 2 orders of magnitude.

Comment: Adding cache=True to numba.jit(nopython=True) gave an error. When I remove nopython=True from the Jit decorator it run, however still the same timings.

Comment: I agree it is not a large dataframe, however I was just following the example from the pandas guide (see original post). As we can see a clear improvement by using cython code, I think this dataframe should be large enough to see improvements with Numba. Thanks for you comments by the way!

Comment: @Rens Instead of adding `cache=True` you can try to simply run the function once with the same inputs before starting the timed run. This should trigger compilation. Could give the function an advantage in terms of CPU cache, so you may want to do the same with the other methods just to be fair :)

Comment: Can you precise the *exact* types of the dataframe columns?

Comment: When I ran the function once before timing, it was  fast AF, so probably indeed some compilation stuff!  Thanks a lot all